# How do I forward all calls to Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice, iphone

I'm on the AT&T network and I want to forward all my calls to my Google Voice number except for calls from my google voice number.

I believe I need to use AT&T's custom call forwarding codes to do this. Can someone point me to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling codes are here:
http://www.wireless.att.com/learn/basics/choosing-features-services/call-forwarding.jsp

I used call forwarding no reply:

```
 Call Forwarding No Reply: Dial *61* plus the 10-digit number to which your
 calls should be forwarded and #. Press
 Send.
```

Comment: How do you shorten the number of rings? Taking this approach AT&T rings many times, then Google voice rings many times. Longer than most would wait to leave a message.

Comment: @Praxiteles I don't think I ever figured that out and I stopped forwarding.